# How to disable device administrator in android programmatically?

Tags: android

I have implemented a Device Administrator application. I am able to active my application by the user. But, it is a matter of sorrow that, I can't retrieve that access.That means I nor the user can disable it again if once it is enabled. I went to Settings>Security>Device Administrators and I found no application there. But then my application is running as a administrator. And sorry for mis-typing code. Actually  now I am on a mobile device. So I couldn't  arrange the code here perfectly.  Forgive me.  Here is my code to enable and lock the screen:-

```
Object obj = getApplicationContext(); DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)((Context)(obj)).getSystemService("device_policy"); obj = new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, ScreenReceiver.class); if(mDPM.isAdminActive(((ComponentName) (obj)))){ mDPM.lockNow(); return; } else{ Intent intent = new Intent("android.app.action.ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN"); intent.putExtra("android.app.extra.DEVICE_ADMIN", ((android.os.Parcelable) (obj))); intent.putExtra("android.app.extra.ADD_EXPLANATION",getString(R.string.hint_des)); startActivity(intent); return; }
```

So please help me saying that how can I disable my application mentioning the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code to disable the device admin,

```
mDPM.removeActiveAdmin(objComponentName);
```

Comment: Thanks bro. It's done. But little bit changes. Like:- mDPM.removeActiveAdmin (((ComponentName)(obj)));..... Thanks^-^